Delete a single value in dataframe based on particular date and time
I have a dataframe and I want to delete a single value based on the date and time, I want to delete the value for Variable 2 on the 2020-06-15 14:00:00 with an option to replace the value 780.45 with NA, or to leave it blank.   I can find answers where the row is deleted based on the datetime but struggling to find where a single value is deleted.
df2 = structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1592226000, 1592226900, 
1592227800, 1592228700, 1592229600, 1592230500), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Variable1 = c(NA, 0.385999999999999, 0.193, 
0.290000000000001, 0.385, 0.576000000000001), Variable2 = c(NA, 1005.87, 
999.05, 1005.32, 780.45, 1100.44)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
class = "data.frame")

Created on 2024-07-05 with reprex v2.1.0

The "tricky" part is to get the date-time in the right format without time zone. One way is to use format.Date
df2$Variable2[format.Date(df2$DateTime, "%F %T") == "2020-06-15 14:00:00"] <- NA

Output
df2
             DateTime Variable1 Variable2
1 2020-06-15 13:00:00        NA        NA
2 2020-06-15 13:15:00     0.386   1005.87
3 2020-06-15 13:30:00     0.193    999.05
4 2020-06-15 13:45:00     0.290   1005.32
5 2020-06-15 14:00:00     0.385        NA
6 2020-06-15 14:15:00     0.576   1100.44


Worked perfectly, thanks very much.  How do I edit the code to delete the value and leave it blank or "missing" (it's for another program that can't analyse NA but can deal with missing values)

NA is the equivalent of missing or blank when you deal with numeric values. If you instead replace it with e.g. <- "" the column will be cast to character because its an empty string. Maybe that's ok if you want to export it anyways.
